# Why does the reputation tab look weird?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-summary

Look at this [user's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266094/unihedron?tab=reputation) reputation points tab.

There are infinite +15s for accepted answer and infinite -45s as voting reversed.

It doesn't say which question's answer was accepted.

Is this a bug?

Here is the [link to screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7aSt.png).

Answer (score 22):

This was caused by a user who has abused the system (quite unnecessarily) by accepting and unnaccepting answers for specific people. He has been suspended for 30 days now.

The people who have lost rep will get it back when the recalc happens.

Comment: I don't care who is running the account. Continuing to grief users by exploiting accepts/unaccepts will result in a suspension for anyone doing it.

Comment: Fix the bug then!

Comment: @bjb568 Oh, I'm sorry we didn't drop everything on a Friday afternoon and work on something that has gone FOR YEARS without a problem. Until one person, who is well-known for borderline-maliciously ... let's be generous... searching for bugs, decided that it would be fun to target people for no benefit whatsoever, well beyond making the "something's broken" point. So. We are going to be looking into fixing this. The fact that it's gonna take some time is not a license to continue exploiting the issue without consequences.