# Received 30 points for accepted answer (from Achievements dialog viewpoint)

Tags: bug, reputation, accepted-answer, achievements-dialog

I'm seeing some weird maths on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1089907/how-to-select-text-with-same-style-token-applied-in-notepad/1097459#1097459).

It is an accepted answer with no upvotes and no downvotes worth 15 points:

[image]

**+15** (correct value) I can see also on **Reputation tab** of my SuperUser profile.

But in reputation overview, there is **+30** points:

[image]

Is this caused by some flaw in reputation summary processing?

Comment: Have a look at the reputation tab of your profile on SU - does it show anything notable? (I can't check myself as I'm on mobile)

Comment: The bug is only in the display of the achievements dialog, in your reputation tab of the profile page there's just +15 for that answer.

Comment: @angussidney – I did (**+15**) and mentioned it in the question before.

Comment: My guess is  the OP accepted and unaccepted twice, though only a dev can confirm since it doesn't appear in the ordinary timeline.

Comment: I wonder if our bugs are related?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280933/achievements-dropdown-misbehaving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was the answer accepted, unaccepted, and then accepted again? Something like that could be the cause of this strange bug, which seems to be visible only in your personal notifications dropdown: your [reputation page](https://superuser.com/users/287473/miroxlav?tab=reputation) shows only +15 for that question:

[image: Screenshot of reputation page]

Does refreshing the page cause the mysterious "+30" to disappear? It's probably just a [caching problem](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). Alternatively, it could be a mistake of the same type that caused [this massive bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256522/why-does-the-reputation-tab-look-weird). You're lucky to get only a +30 instead of a +15; compare with this guy:

[image: Shadow Wizard's rep on 15 May 2015]

---

UPDATE: the OP reports that the problem has now disappeared, so apparently this was just a temporary glitch.

Comment: I cannot answer whether the OP has *accepted, unaccepted, and then accepted the answer again*. If it was done, it was done quickly so I did not notice. I can only confirm that non-cached refresh has no effect...

Comment: Judging by another bug report about the achievements dialog, I believe that's not the case, but rather something is borked behind the scenes. /cc @miroxlav

Comment: Now I observe two separate issues in achievements (not sure whether they have common cause or not):  (1) answer score is double-counted (2) upvotes for this question come delayed some 30 minutes /cc @KateGregory

Comment: @ShadowWizard – All right, now both issues seem to be fixed. Perhaps if there was some outcome, I'd accept is as the answer.

Comment: @miroxlav probably some temporary glitch, don't think it deserves a full answer, but of course would be nice to get one, from SE dev. :)