# Achievements dropdown misbehaving

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

The achievements dropdown is not showing all the rep I earned:

[image]

The question was asked and answered today. I have not hit the rep cap. I have never seen caching be an issue in the dropdown before. I first noticed when the question was accepted - I saw it on the main page as accepted, but I had no rep gain from that, so assumed someone else's answer was accepted. While I was loading the page, my profile, the page and so on, another upvote came in. Yet through these events the dropdown continued to just say +10. Even when the tag badge appeared, the rep change stayed the same.

Comment: and I can see (because the page updates itself) that I got an upvote here, but the dropdown is completely unaware of it.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the achievements dialog is borked today, see [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280931/received-30-points-for-accepted-answer-from-achievements-dialog-viewpoint). Probably something went out of synch somewhere. :(

Comment: My rep gains on main meta aren't showing up in my global inbox (though the new privilege I just gained here is). Not sure about any other sites.

Comment: Just seems delayed. It now shows me +5 (for 1 upvote) though the question is at 4 upvotes

Comment: I just had this problem as well, on Puzzling.

Comment: Yeah, there is one hour delay between gaining reputation and until  it appears in the achievements dialog.

Comment: Is this fixed now for you? My MSE rep is now all appearing as it should.

Comment: right now it seems to have all of today's action in it, yes, @randal'thor

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be gone now.
(I can verify it on my account because I was experiencing it before, too.)

If someone from SE devs won't provide further details, let's conclude this was sort of temporary issue which has been resolved.